# Is there a way to write a macro that will loop to text join multiple rows of data in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

For example I need to join the text in each of these lines, but the document is thousands of lines so a macro would be ideal. The part that I am stuck on is that I don't know how to write an if statement in a loop that will link the texts in a paragraph and then jump down to the next paragraph of lines and do the same thing until the end of the sheet. You will notice each of them is delimited with a blank row in between on purpose. Any suggestions on how to do this? The example in cell G2 is how I want each beginning sentence to look.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `=TEXTJOIN()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes I do have =TextJoin() in G2 but i would like to not have to manually type in the formula for each of the paragraphs throughout the original document because there are thousands of lines like the picture shows.

Comment: Then create a loop that goes group by group, and joins the blocks of text together -- then post the code you're using, and any errors, etc.

Comment: Type a dynamic formula and just apply it to the whole column. Only need to add the formula once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`SpecialCells()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells) method of `Range` object

```
Sub TextJoin()
    Dim area As Range

    With Worksheets("MySheetName") ' change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        For Each area In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            .Cells(area(1, 1).Row, "G").Value = Join(Application.Transpose(area.Value))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @T.M., thanks. Actually _short & clear_ is my prime goal when coding. And when the two features conflict, I prefer the former than the latter

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider marking the answer as accepted to direct future readers, too...

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    vDB = Ws.UsedRange
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To n)

    For i = 1 To n
        If vDB(i, 1) = "" Then
            vR(i) = vbCrLf & vbCrLf '
        Else
            vR(i) = vDB(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1") = Join(vR, " ")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"i would like to not have to manually type in the formula for each of the paragraphs throughout the original document"*

Just to demonstrate you can use `TEXTJOIN` functionality in VBA using `Evaluate()`.
Most of this code is based on @HTH 's really fine & short solution :-;

```
Sub TxtJoin()
    Dim area As Range
    With Sheet1       ' << change to your current sheet's Code(Name)
        For Each area In .Range("A4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            .Cells(area(1, 1).Row, "G").Value = Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("" "",FALSE," & area.Address & ")")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

If you should prefer, you could add the formulae by replacing the cells assignment by

```
.Cells(area(1, 1).Row, "G").Formula2 = "=TEXTJOIN("" "",FALSE," & area.Address & ")"
```